# How to notice if a tool in the apt repository is still being maintained/which version I should use?

Tags: apt, package-management

Well as per title, is there a cnonical way to understand if a certain library/tool is still actively being maintained?

When searching online for problems you often see blog post (or answers here) from like 10 years ago. And this made me wonder: how do I know if the tools specified there are still "good", maintained and safe.

This is especially problematic as it's just all too easy to type `sudo apt-get install XYZ` and ignore anything else just hoping it works. Does the apt repository itself give me a warning if a certain tool is buggy/has security breaches?

Or am I just at the merci of luckily finding a counter blog post for said tool?

Comment: Look at where it came from, was it from *main* which means it will get security fixes completed for the *life* of the release you're using (9 months if non-LTS, 5 years if LTS).  If it's from *universe* or community supported; it may only have 9 months, but if included on an ISO & supported by a *flavor* of Ubuntu, it may have 9 months or 3 years (not all releases are LTS; ie. two of 18.04 products came with only 9 months; one team provided further fixes via PPA - read the release notes!)

Comment: Yes if a LTS release, MOTU's can apply fixes for up to five years for *universe* if bugs are raised, but there are no guarantees on that (they apply to *main* & *restricted*).  If it's 3rd party PPA or elsewhere, it's on you to perform the checks yourself.  You can use `apt-cache policy` to view where a package came from (as example; many ways actually).   How you look varies on what package, where from & I've only covered some *deb* packages (not *snap* or other packages that are available)....

Comment: @guiverc how do I know where it's from when I just see the command line to install?

Comment: I mentioned `apt-cache policy`, so assuming your XYZ package was `lubuntu-default-settings` a query tells me the package on my system came from `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe`; ie. official archive for my release (*lunar*) and from *universe* so it's community-support only; meaning 9 months for *lunar*.  If my release was *jammy* for example; that would mean 3 years of support (LTS for community) with guarantee, but further 2 (getting to 5 years) only if bug is raised & MOTU patches (ie. 3 years only is guaranteed; where 5 year guarantee applies to *main*)

Comment: @guiverc could you make this into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Look at where it came from, was it from ***main*** which means it will get security fixes completed for the life of the release you're using (9 months if non-LTS, 5 years if LTS). If it's from ***universe*** or community supported; it may only have 9 months, but if included on an ISO & supported by a flavor of Ubuntu, it may have 9 months or 3 years (not all releases are LTS; ie. two of 18.04 products came with only 9 months; one team (Ubuntu Studio 18.04) provided further fixes via PPA - so read the release notes & notices!)

Yes if a LTS release, MOTU's can apply fixes for up to five years for universe if bugs are raised, but there are no guarantees on that (they apply to main & restricted).

If it's 3rd party **PPA** or elsewhere, it's on you to perform the checks yourself. You can use `apt-cache policy` to view where a package came from (*as example; many ways actually*). No formula can predict these packages support, so you need to research this yourself.

How you look varies on what package, where from & I've only covered some *deb* packages (not *snap* or other package types that are available)

```
guiverc@hp8200-ubu:~$   apt-cache policy lubuntu-default-settings
lubuntu-default-settings:
  Installed: 23.04.4
  Candidate: 23.04.4
  Version table:
 *** 23.04.4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
guiverc@hp8200-ubu:~$
```

Assuming your XYZ package was `lubuntu-default-settings` a query tells me the package on my system came from `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe`; ie. official archive for my release (*lunar*) and from ***universe*** so it's community-support only; meaning 9 months for *lunar*.

If my release was *jammy* (22.04) for example; that would mean 3 years of support (LTS for community) with *guarantee*, but further 2 (getting to 5 years) only if bug is raised & MOTU patches (ie. 3 years only is guaranteed; where 5 year guarantee applies to main)

- *MOTU = 'Master of the Universe'; developer with rights to make changes during the life of the release to 'universe' packages; Core-Devs have this right too.*
- *I think I used `lubuntu-default-settings` as it's easy to recognize (*at least to me*) it's a package included on our Lubuntu ISOs, thus would come with 3 year guarantee where it was a LTS release; also maybe as we recently changed it*